# UILabel shrink / expand frame to fit text in autolayout?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, constraints

Is there any way in which you could set a font size for a label, and then make the label frame (rectangle bounds) to shrink / expand to fit the font size ? This is the inverse of `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth`, in which you resize the text to fit the frame.

So let's say I have a label, that can contain any kind of text in it... I want to resize the frame of the label to exactly fit the text... so after, I can properly use anchor constraints.

I'm looking for something like `adjustFrameWidthHeightToFitText`.

Comment: Could you please provide a code that does not work and a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

Set vertical and horizontal content hugging priority to 1000, then the label will exactly fit the content.

Comment: Ok kind sir, I will try this and come back with an answer. So far I tried using sizeToFit() then setting constraint to match the frame.width... which works also, but requires dynamic constraint updating.

Comment: Setting content hugging priority to 1000 doesn't work well for me. I'm already using higher hugging priority for something else and if I set this also, then that something else gets resized and I don't want to. I will stick to my dynamic constraint to sizeToFit that seems to work for now.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't set the height constraint, and set the number of lines to something like 15-20 (depends on your text size), then the interface builder will take care of it.